# Accessing Openfire outside Azure VM not working

Tags: azure, xmpp, openfire, converse.js

I have created a virtual machine in Microsoft Azure. I have installed Openfire in the virtual machine. I have configured IIS to deploy my ConverseJS and I have established BOSCH connection from ConverseJS to Openfire. I have some users in openfire and I am able to Sign in the users inside the VM. While trying to access the ConverseJS site from my machine using the cloudapp.azure.com url I got the website. But I cannot Login into the XMPP server From outside the VM. Anyone please help. I am very new to this set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works local but not over the internet I assume its an firewall issue.
Have you opened the Port in the Firewall of your VM and the Endpoint in the Azure VM configuration?

Comment: You are right.Issue was with my port.7070 was closed.